# Blink background color of text widget when value change Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

i want to create a custom widget have input is String and blink background color when value of text widget change in flutter.
I'm not good at English.
Ex i am want to blink background when value change same img
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT1KV.png)

I try to use timer.perious but not working

Comment: Please provide a code sample so that we can see what you tried so far. A minimal reproducible example (with no external dependencies)

Comment: try to use chatGPT 